# Low consuming loop in C

Tags: c, events, while-loop, cpu-usage, sdl-2

I started to play with user interfaces in C with SDL2, window creation and keyboard events.

I realised that my app was consuming a lot of CPU (> 95%), probably because I have a while loop waiting for an event to come.

How does every other apps manage to not used all the CPU and still be able to respond to an event ?

Comment: Maybe the other anonymous applications you refer to don't continuously loop, but uses timers or some other event handling for drawing? Maybe they draw at a specific frame-rate and does some sleeping in between?

Comment: Well, not waiting for the event is a good plan.

Comment: If I don't wait for the event how am I supposed to detect it ? @MartinJames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@artonge,

I had the same problem. I wrote a Sleep(..) in the loop and the resource utilization did come down.

```
Sleep(int milliSeconds);
```

Comment: Initentionally doing nothing, and adding latency, will reduce CPU utilization, yes.  It is, however, a design that gives Sleep() a bad name:(

Comment: I thought sleep would add to much latency but it doesn't, thanks !